# Shouldn't this code lead to a deadlock?

Tags: c++, c++11, deadlock

I have a class which contains a mutex and an object, each time I need to access the contained object, a method is called to lock the mutex and return te contained object, let's see the code:

```
template <typename MUTEX, typename RESOURCE>
class LockedResource
{
    using mutex_t    = MUTEX;
    using resource_t = RESOURCE;

    mutex_t    m_mutex;
    resource_t m_resource;

public:
        template <typename ... ARGS>
        LockedResource(ARGS &&... args) :
                m_resource(std::forward<ARGS>(args) ...)
        {}

    class Handler
    {
        std::unique_lock<mutex_t> m_lock;      // unique lock
        resource_t                &m_resource; // Ref to resource

        friend class LockedResource;

        Handler(mutex_t &a_mutex, resource_t &a_resource) :
            m_lock(a_mutex),       // mutex automatically locked
            m_resource(a_resource)
        { std::cout << "Resource locked\n"; }

    public:
        Handler(Handler &&a_handler) :
            m_lock(std::move(a_handler.m_lock)),
            m_resource(a_handler.m_resource)
        { std::cout << "Moved\n"; }

        ~Handler() // mutex automatically unlocked
        { std::cout << "Resource unlocked\n"; }

        RESOURCE *operator->()
        { return &m_resource; }
    };

    Handler get()
    { return {m_mutex, m_resource}; }
};

template <typename T> using Resource = LockedResource<std::mutex, T>;
```

The idea behind this code is to *wrap* an object and protect it from multiple access from multiple threads; the wrapped object have private visibility and the only way to access it is through the internal class `Handler`, the expected usage is the following:

```
LockedResource<std::mutex, Foo> locked_foo;
void f()
{
    auto handler = locked_foo.get(); // this will lock the locked_foo.m_mutex;
    handler->some_foo_method();
    // going out of the scope will call the handler dtor and
    // unlock the locked_foo.m_mutex;
}
```

So, if I'm not mistaken, calling the `LockedResource::get` method creates a `LockedResource::Handle` value which locks the `LockedResource::m_mutex` for the entire lifetime of the `Handle`... but I must be mistaken because the code below doesn't cause a deadlock:

```
LockedResource<std::mutex, std::vector<int>> locked_vector{10, 10};

int main()
{
/*1*/  auto vec = locked_vector.get(); // vec = Resource<vector>::Handler
/*2*/  std::cout << locked_vector.get()->size() << '\n';
/*3*/  std::cout << vec->size() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting the line `/*1*/` to lock the `locked_vector.m_mutex` and then the line `/*2*/` try to lock the same already locked mutex causing deadlock, but the output is the following:

> ```
> Resource locked
> Resource locked
> 10
> Resource unlocked
> 10
> Resource unlocked
> ```

- Shouldn't the second `::get()` lead to a deadlock?
- I'm accessing the wrapped resource through the same lock or I am misunderstanding something?

Here is the <kbd>[example code](http://ideone.com/COJjBf)</kbd>.

Comment: If the mutex implementation was `C++11` compliant, than you would run into a dead-lock (or an exception could be thrown, or an `assert` triggers...). However, if `std::mutex` is a wrapper around a recursive mutex (which is common on embedded systems), then you would see the aforementioned output.

Comment: With `GCC 5.1` the behaviour is different, for example. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/946de4b3c835fa89).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, quick tests show the following:

1. GCC - shows the output which is shown in the question
2. Clang - process killed on the online compiler I've used. So deadlock.
3. MSVC2013 - "device or resource busy: device or resource busy" - is thrown. It detected an attempt to lock the already locked mutex on the same thread.

What standard has to say about it?

> 30.4.1.2.1/4 [ Note: A program **may** deadlock if the thread that owns a mutex object calls lock() on that object. If the implementation
>   can detect the deadlock, a resource_deadlock_would_occur error condition **may** be observed. — end note ]

But according to 30.4.1.2/13 it should throw one of these:

```
— resource_deadlock_would_occur — if the implementation detects that a deadlock would occur. 
— device_or_resource_busy — if the mutex is already locked and blocking is not possible.
```

<strike>So the answer is yes, what you observe is an incorrect behavior. It should either block or throw but not proceed as nothing has happened.</strike>

The behavior observed is possible since you have UB in the code. According to 17.6.4.11, violation of a *Requires* clause is UB and in 30.4.1.2/7 we have the following requirement:

> **Requires**: If m is of type std::mutex, std::timed_mutex, or
>   std::shared_timed_mutex, the calling thread does not own the mutex.

Thanks to @T.C. for pointing out about UB.

Comment: Before  you mentioned it, I didn't tested the code with other compilers but using [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox) instead of [Ideone](http://ideone.com/) I get the same results as you... I wasn't expecting that the locking behaviour varies between compilers and versions :O

Comment: The behavior observed is perfectly correct. Locking a mutex you already own violates [thread.mutex.requirements.mutex]/p7, and violating a *Requires* clause is UB. Also, notes are non-normative.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this *specific* mutex/resource implementation, but it's common for such synchronization primitives to contain a LOCK COUNT, and to allow the same thread to lock the same object multiples times.

When the mutex has been unlocked the same number of times as it was locked, then another thread is free to lock it.

Comment: That should be a recursive mutex, then. OP doesn't use one

Comment: FWIW, I think the downvote for your answer was a wrong.