# Access internal object through a proxy object

Tags: templates, c++11, operator-overloading, rvalue-reference

This question is related with a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205040/shouldnt-this-code-lead-to-a-deadlock) of mine.

Let's say we have a class which wraps an object and returns it through a proxy:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo
{
    template <typename ... ARGS>
    Foo(ARGS &&... args) : value(std::forward<ARGS>(args) ...) {}

    struct Proxy
    {
        Proxy(T &v) : value{v} {}

        T *operator->() { return &value; }
        T &operator*() { return value; }
        friend std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const Proxy &p) { return o << p.value; }

    private:
        T &value;
    };

    Proxy get() { return {value}; }

private:
    T value{};
};
```

Is intended to be used this way:

```
Foo<int> integer{100};
auto integer_proxy = integer.get();
std::cout << integer_proxy << '\n'; // 100

*integer_proxy *= 2;
std::cout << integer_proxy << '\n'; // 200
```

The idea is to access to the wrapped object **only** through proxy class instances which are created calling `Foo<T>::get()`, about the rationale behind the proxy class, is to *protect* the wrapped object controlling how is it accessed (with a lock, for example). But nothing prevents to access the wrapped object without using a proper `Foo<T>::Proxy` instance, for example:

```
Foo<int> integer{100};
std::cout << integer.get() << '\n'; // 100

*integer.get() *= 2;
std::cout << integer.get() << '\n'; // 200
```

In the code above a `Foo<T>::Proxy` object is created and destroyed in each `Foo<T>::get()` call instead of storing it in an instance and accesing through it.

#### What have you tried?

I thought that overloading `get()` function when the `Foo` instance acts as al rvalue could do the trick:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo
{
    // ...
    Proxy get()    { return {value}; }
    Proxy get() && { throw std::logic_error{"forbiden"}; return {}; }
    // ...
};
```

But the code above fails to compile:

> ```
> error: 'Foo<T>::Proxy Foo<T>::get() &&' cannot be overloaded
>      Proxy get() && { throw std::logic_error{"forbidden"}; return {}; }
>            ^~~
> error: with 'Foo<T>::Proxy Foo<T>::get()'
>      Proxy get()    { return {value}; }
>            ^~~
> ```

After some test-and-error I managed to compile the code this way:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo
{
    // ...
    Proxy get() &  { return {value}; }
    Proxy get() && { throw std::logic_error{"forbidden"}; return {}; }
    // ...
};
```

But it doesn't prevent the missuse of the `get()` function either. Also, the error raises in runtime while compile time would be a better choice... but replacing the `std::logic_error` with `static_assert(false, "forbidden")` causes the code fail even if the static asserted function isn't called:

```
Foo<int> integer{100};
std::cout << integer.get() << '\n'; // Still valid, no std::logic_error thrown
```

Then I tried to change the `Foo<T>::Proxy::operator->()` in the same way as the `Foo<T>::get()`, but changing `int` by `std::vector<int>` (after all `int` does not have members to be used with this operator), then I've achieved with the expected behaviour:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo
{
    // ...
    struct Proxy
    {
        T *operator->() & { return &value; }
        T *operator->() && { throw std::logic_error{"forbidden"}; return nullptr; }
        // ...
    };

    // ...
};

int main()
{
    Foo<std::vector<int>> vector{10, 10};
    auto vector_proxy = vector.get();
    std::cout << vector_proxy->size() << '\n';
    std::cout << vector.get()->size() << '\n'; // logic_error thrown!

    return {};
}
```

But if I change the `throw` sentence by a `static_assert` it fails even when the `// logic_error thrown!` line is comented (so it's not called); and this doesn't prevent the missuse of the `get()` function either.

---

Questions:

- Is there a way to achieve the desired behaviour for the `Foo<T>::get()` function?
- Why overloading a function with lvalue reference causes compilation error and overloading reference and lvalue reference does not?

  ```
  // Error
  struct Err {
      Proxy get()    { ... }
      Proxy get() && { ... }
  }

  // Ok
  struct Ok {
      Proxy get() &  { ... }
      Proxy get() && { ... }
  }
  ```
- Why a `static_assert` forced to fail on the body of template class member function causes the compilation error? I've believed that unused template class functions aren't compiled (maybe is only applied to template functions?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `=delete` the overloads you don't want to be callable, and you'll get compile-time errors.

```
Proxy get() && = delete;
```

or, in many cases, overload `&` and not `&&`.

Practically, if you want to forbid using temporary proxies, overload `&` on the proxy not on the source of the proxy.

```
    T *operator->()& { return &value; }
    T &operator*()& { return value; }
    friend std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const Proxy&&p) = delete;
    friend std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const Proxy &p) { return o << p.value; }
```

using `=delete` only when the existence of a `const&` overloads permits using rvalues and you want to block it.